# Поддержка аппаратных устройств (разные версии аппаратуры и протоколов). Какой архитектурный подход выбрать

Tags: c++, ооп, архитектура

Пишу утилиту для работы с разрабатываемой аппаратурой. Возник вопрос по организации архитектуры ПО в части абстракций аппаратуры. Суть вопроса: имеется несколько версий аппаратного блока (появился дополнительный функционал). И есть протокол общения с устройством. Протокол так же имеет несколько версий.

Чтобы получить комфортный интерфейс по работе с аппаратурой из основной части ПО, предполагаю сделать следующее.
Создать класс устройства, который будет содержать все возможные методы по работе с протоколами всех версий. Но при этом у него можно будет спросить ЧТО из этого функционала он поддерживает. Дальнейшее поведение программы будет определяться ответом устройства.
Мои попытки с использованием наследования оказались не продуктивными. Много классов, постоянная приводка типов...

Ранее не сталкивался с такой задачей - буду признателен если поделитесь своим опытом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обязательно надо на этапе выполнения? Может перетащить на этап сборки задание целевого девайса?

Comment: Нет, целевое устройство формируется динамически. Программа должна это поддерживать во время выполнения.

Comment: На [COM](https://rsdn.org/article/com/introcom.xml) смотрели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Создается перечислимый тип набора функций устройства.

Например Action с полным перечнем

Action.Temp

Action.Light

Action.Bell

....

2. Создается абстрактный базовый класс Device в котором реализуется:

2.1. конструктор, принимающий на вход параметры текущего устройства и создающий необходимый экземпляр класса-наследника.

2.2. метод, определяющий наличие необходимого интерфейса. Например
bool hasFunc(Action _action). На вход подается нужная операция, возвращается есть эта операция на данном устройстве или нет. По умолчанию возвращает false.

3.3. метод, вызывающий нужную функцию устройства anyType invoke(Action _action, anyType _parm). На вход подаются необходимые параметры. На выходе получаем результат. Передавать параметры можно либо с помощью абстрактного класса параметров, либо контейнером, либо любым другим способом, на что хватит фантазии разработчика. Метод либо делаем абстрактным, либо делаем заглушку, которая по умолчанию ничего не делает.

3. Создаются классы потомки для устройств с наследованием от базового класса. Эти классы каждый должен реализовывать нужный протокол.

Например:

Device_V1_P1

Device_V1_P2

Device_V2_P1

Device_V2_P2

Device_V2_P3

В каждом классе делается реализация методов hasFunc и invoke. В методе invoke вызываются нужные методы управления устройством в зависимости от переданного в параметрах типа функции и ее параметров.

---

Итого:

На выходе мы имеем четкую структуру классов, реализующую нужную функциональность с единой точкой входа (базовый абстрактный класс) и очень простым интерфейсом взаимодействия.

При необходимости данная структура может дополняться и изменяться.

Аналогично можно продумать структуру классов, задающих параметры для выполнения нужных функций.

Вызывающий класс должен сначала проверить возможность вызова нужной функции, и, если это возможно, вызвать ее с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Андрей, ответ великолепный. Был уже близок к этому же подходу. Оставалось додумать как реализовать унифицированный интерфейс. Вы подсказали. Думаю , что подход найден, осталось воплотить. Успехов вам!

Comment: Идея отталкиваться от протокола грамотная. Осталось отбросить излишние  ООП-шные абстракции